# Swift 3: Cannot invoke dataTask with an argument list of type error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I'm beginner in iOS. I have searched web and couldn't find answer that would solve my problem. **Stuck and have no idea what to do and how to search for solution.**

I'm following the tutorial which is based on Swift 2. The following method is showing error.

```
func downloadBooks(bookTitle: String) {
    let stringURL = "GET https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=\(bookTitle)"

    guard let URL = URL(string: stringURL) else {
        print("url problems")
        return
    }

    let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

I have made all adjustments suggested by Xcode, but no further hints.

Moreover, original portion of code from tutorial was like this:

```
guard let URL = NSURL(string: stringURL) else {
    print("url problems")
    return
}
```

Then Xcode suggested to add `as URL` like below:

```
let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL as URL)
```

Both of these versions are showing **no error**. So what is the difference? Which one should I use?

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: You don't need the `GET ` at the beginning of the URL.

Comment: @AndyIbanez really? But it was taken from tutorial. Then the author is wrong?

Comment: If your URL becomes nil then yes. Data tasks are implied to be get anyway.

Comment: @AndyIbanez so I need to just leave URL?

Comment: @AndyIbanez Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Swift 3 the compiler wants native `URLRequest`

```
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url) // use a lowercase variable name, URL is a native struct in Swift 3
```

But with your particular syntax you don't even need the request

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in ...
```

nor the annotations

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in ...
```

Comment: Tried both of your solutions and all of them are working. Then what is the difference? Which one I should leave?

Comment: The request is actually not needed for GET tasks. You need it for POST tasks passing headers and the POST data. So omit the request.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, one more question please. What is the difference between `NSURL` and just `URL`? Also between `NSMutableURLRequest` and `URLRequest` ?

Comment: Swift 3 uses new types `URL` and `URLRequest` – as well as many other Foundation types without the `NS` prefix –  which are structs aka value types (unlike the Foundation counterparts which are classes aka reference types). It's a part of the Swift philosophy to change a lot of lightweight classes to structs for performance reasons.

Comment: So whenever I encounter in tutorials prefix NS, I should look for the new naming for that class, because the chances are it was changed. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, sort of. Please watch the WWDC 2016 Video [What's New in Foundation for Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/207/)

Comment: Thank you once again. Sorry for bombarding with questions. I just find it a little bit hard to move from Android to iOS. Just need more time and practice to get experience. Will definitely read more about fundamental concepts of iOS and Swift.